# Running python file in google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

[image]

Hello, it might be a dumb question, but as you can see in the image, I want to run datasets.py file. I am inside the mos4d folder. However, the error says it can not find the mos4d module in datasets.py. Can somebody help me to solve this error please?

I am trying to run this project : https://github.com/PRBonn/4DMOS#installation on my google-colab.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I got this error was the MinkowskiEngine was not installed on GPU runtime properly. After installing MinkowskiEngine, the error was solved.

Comment: Consider marking your answer as correct by pressing the checkmark.

Answer (score 1):

When importing a custom module, you have to do the following steps:

1. Mount your google drive to colab

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

2. Append the path of `mos4d` module into colab path

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/content/drive/My Drive/4DMOS/src/')
```

Looks like you've managed to mount your drive. It should be able to import `mos4d` by appending the path.

#### Update at 2022-07-25

I've checked your path again and the append path should be modified to `'/content/4DMOS/src/'`.

In the beginning, I thought that you were trying to mount your Google Drive to the colab notebook. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

I've created a python file named `utils.py` and defined `load_poses` function inside

```py
def load_poses():
    print("Load poses imported")
```

Here's the test in my colab notebook, it can be imported successfully as the following image
[image: Import test for 4DMOS]

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, it shows the same error.